# Iterate through table cells using for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, html

objective is to apply fizzbuzz into the numbers that are in the html table cell.
So get the number in each cell of the table, iterate to put out "fizz" if its multiple of 3, "buzz" if its multiple of 5, or "fizzbuzz" if multiple of both 3 and 5.
below is what I have.

html

```
 <tbody>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>15</td></tr>
  </tbody>
```

and my JS

```
  var table = $(this);

  var tds = $(this).find('td');
  var tableItems = "";

  for (var i = 0; parseInt(tds.eq(i).text()); i++) {
      tableItems += "<tr><td>";
      if ((i % 3 === 0) && (i % 5 === 0)) {
          tableItems += "FizzBuzz";
      }
      else if (i % 3 === 0) {
          tableItems += "Fizz";
      }
      else (i % 5 === 0) {
          tableItems += "Buzz";
      }
      tableItems += "</td></tr>";
  }
  $(".fizzer").append(tableItems);
}
```

Seems like i need to find a way for i to iterate through parseInt(tds.eq(i).text());
but having trouble...help?

This is the output i get:
FizzBuzz
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz

Comment: can you better define "apply fizzbuzz into the numbers"? even better, can you provide a sample output ?

Comment: where is fizzer class defined??...moreover there is an extra curly brace at the last line..

Comment: You could use native [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) interface.

Comment: Are you trying to change the 3 into Fizz, the 4 into Uncool., the 5 into Buzz and the 15 into FizzBuzz?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something line this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        var td = $(this).find('td:first');
        var value = td.html();
        td.html(parseValue(value));
    });

    function parseValue(value) {
        if (value % 15 == 0) {
            text = 'FizzBuzz';
        } else if (value % 5 == 0) {
            text = 'Buzz';
        } else if (value % 3 == 0) {
            text = 'Fizz';
        } else {
            text = 'Uncool.';
        }
        return text;
    }
});
```